# О закрытии вопросов, на которые нельзя дать объективный ответ

Tags: обсуждение

Выглядит это так: Невозможно дать объективный ответ. Скорее всего, ответы на этот вопрос будут основаны **на мнениях**, а не на фактах и цитатах.

Получается парадокс:  **Есть мнение, что ответы на этот вопрос будут основаны на мнениях.**

А это мнение  на чем основано? Если обоснования у него нет, но оно может быть неверным.

Для закрытия вопроса нужно 5 голосов.

А  из пяти предположительно неверных  мнений  всегда получается одно верное?

И задачка: Какова вероятность того, что пять необоснованных мнений приведут к закрытию интересного вопроса?

Добавлю еще несколько слов **о закрытии домашних заданий**. На форуме крайне отрицательно относятся к этой теме. Мы не любим поощрять лентяев и выполнять их работу. Но дело в том, что только самые наивные из них присылают такие вопросы: **Расставить и объяснить знаки препинания**. А далее следует **список из 10 предложений или хотя бы из одного.** Более продвинутые напишут так: Помогите разобраться, какой знак поставить, запятую или тире. Я думаю, что тире, но сомневаюсь. И вот уж перед нами **не лентяй, а труженик.**

Так что идея воспитания довольно проблематична и не вегда решаема, в то время как в качестве домашних заданий могут закрываться интересные вопросы. Их авторы просто не знают, как их правильно "оформлять".

Comment: Не знаю, кто _заминусовал_ Ваш вопрос. Но я поддержу Вас — в стремлении находить интересность там, где другие ее не видят.  P. S. Сейчас я мало участвую в **жизни** форума. Мой спасательный круг умер — моими страшно заботливыми руками. (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/456730/%d0%94%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d0%b3%d0%b0) Тяжело.

Comment: Римма, спасибо за голос. Там, кажется, даже два минуса было. Но, как говорится, как бы ни отмечали, но лишь бы замечали. А вот вашу запись я не совсем поняла, хотя мне и хотелось бы понять.

Comment: Бездомный беспородный щенок (грязный и вонючий, со сломанным хвостом и кровоточащей лапой) появился в доме почти восемнадцать лет назад. И оказался _спасательным кругом_ — в очень сложное для меня время. (Я просто дала ссылку на заданный мною когда-то вопрос: "Детский вопрос: куда ходит доходяга?") Он больше никуда и никак не ходит...

Comment: Вот видите, _Sharon_, "процесс пошёл".